# RGBDSLAM Data Collection

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using RGBDSLAM on Ubuntu 11.10, on ROS Electric, and a Kinect camera. My goal is to basically move around my room with the camera and **create a 3-D map of my room**. I guess that just means turning up the RGBDSLAM GUI on the terminal, and then hitting space to record data from the video stream generated. I am wondering, after this, I can simply save these data, but do I have to do anything further? Say, for instance, write some code to further process this data? Or that is enough for the **sole purpose** I am trying to achieve?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37865/rgbdslam-data-collection/) by [periphery](https://answers.ros.org/users/2488/periphery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-11-20**:
Hi periphery, Were you able to get rgbdslam running on ur system using kinect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on what you want your map to be, but in principle yes.
If it should just be a big point cloud, saving is all you need. Maybe trigger optimization (Key "o") before you do so.
If you want a volumetric map, use the octomap_server and use "send whole model" (and trigger the octomap_saver later).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0